# Mongoose findById query does not return a result. Object is always null.

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

findById doesn't return a result. `const course` object is null everytime I log.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mongo-exercises', { useNewUrlParser: true });

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    author: String,
    tags: [ String ],
    date: Date,
    price: Number,
    isPublished: Boolean
});

const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

async function updateCourse(id){
        const course = await Course.findById(id);
        if(!course) return;

        course.isPublished = true;
        course.author = 'Another Author';

        const result = await course.save();
        console.log(result);
}

updateCourse('5a68fde3f09ad7646ddec17e');
```

Comment: `null` means that a document with that `_id` wasn't found. Can you update your question to include the document you're expecting to find?

Comment: The connection to your DB is fishy.

Aren't you suppose to add ':27017'(or whatever port your mongod is listening on) after the localhost bit

Comment: You code looks ok. I tested exact same function body + `findById` and `save` with just different Schema. You need to provide some sample data please

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved. I noticed that when I imported the collection prior to updating by `.findById()`; the id's of the objects were saved as Strings instead of  `ObjectID`